# Вывод графиков на страницу

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода графиков на страницу. Пытаюсь подключить Highcharts через json, но не могу понять, где и как обработать данные, полученные из json-запроса. Или может есть еще какие-то способы вывода графиков.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObject = eval('(' + JSONtext + ')');
```

После этой строки myObject получит все свойства, описанные в JSONtext.
Я так понимаю, с получением этого текста проблем нет?

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался. eval() был только одной из проблем))

Answer (score 1):

Отличная библиотека [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).
Пример из своего кода приведу

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
    $.plot($('#profile_life_activity'),
           [{data: profile_life_activity,
         lines: {show: true},
         points: {show: true},
            color:'#008bd6'},
        {data: user_profile_life_activity,
         lines: {show: true},
         points: {show: true},
            color:'#e7371f'},
        {data: intersection,
             lines: {show: false},
             points: {show: true},
                color:'#00ff00'}
           ],
           {
            grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
            yaxis: {min: 0,
            ticks: 9,
            max: 9},
        xaxis: {ticks: 7}
        });
    });
```

где в data как раз попадает JSON-объект

Comment: Спасибо. но я все-таки сделал в Highcharts. А JSON получал через ajax